# Windows 7 right click "Send to" file context menu

Tags: windows, windows-7

When I right click a file (in any folder) I see an option "Send to" and inside

Desktop
Documents
...

and a bunch of other locations.

How can I add my own location, ie "C:\stuff" to this context menu?

Answer (score 6):

Open file explorer and navigate to: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo

Once in the SendTo folder, right click -> New -> Shortcut

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the default shortcuts in the SendTo menu, there are hidden options that are exposed if you hold down shift while right clicking the targeted icon. 
(This is Windows 7 only)

The easiest way to add your own is to type "shell:sendto" in a file explorer, ( or start -> run -> sendto ) and place whatever shortcut you deem useful. As mentioned before you can add shortcuts to programs as well as directories.
(This is more universal)

**[HERE](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/stupid-geek-tricks-secret-items-on-the-windows-7-send-to-menu/)** is a nice article with a picture instructions.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to shortcuts to folders, you can add shortcuts to apps. for example, add a shortcut to "send to notepad" to open a file in the notepad app. a useful function for a developer.